# C++ standard type sizes in stdint.h

Tags: c++

I'm using std::uint32_t and for some reason it's a different data type than unsigned long which is an unsigned 32 on my platform (ARM Cortex M4 K20) ...  Any ideas?

Nevermind I guess sometimes you want variable-sized types:

```
typedef unsigned short Integer16;
typedef std::uint32_t Integer32;

typedef unsigned int FastInteger16;
typedef unsigned long FastInteger32;
```

Any problems with this?

Comment: What does `sizeof()` report for the two types?

Comment: 4 on both unsigned long and std::uint32_t...

Comment: @RyanBrown: So `uint32_t` is a 32-bit type as it should be. What's the problem?

Comment: I don't understand your second question: "*[how to determine if] `std::uint32_t is not 32 bits`*?". Trust me, `std::uint32_t` **will always be** 32 bits.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't match unsigned long 32-bit types defined already...

Comment: @Ryan: your implementation has *two* different unsigned 32-bit types. `uint32_t` can't be the same type as both of them, and `unsigned long` is the one that it's a different type from.

Comment: I know there are two (even though there shouldnt be), is it possible to do a define that solves this issue so my code can be platform independant and still work with legacy code?

Comment: @RyanBrown: depends on the legacy code. If it's written on the assumption that `uint32_t` and `unsigned long` are the same type then possibly you can't work around it, you might have to fix the legacy code. I don't know what you mean by, "there shouldn't be" two types. The standard requires that `int` and `long` are distinct types. If you think the standard shouldn't require that then you could take it up with the standard committee, but you'll lose because there are good reasons why it works that way :-)

Comment: Is it faster to use a 32 bit integer than a 16-bit integer on a 32-bit platform?  That would be the only reason you'd want a variable-size type

Comment: Re: "even though there shouldn't be" - there's nothing in the C or C++ standard that prohibits having two 32-bit integral types. In fact, it's quite common.

Comment: @RyanBrown: The reason that the C++ standard makes `int` a different-sized type on different platforms isn't solely to do with picking the fastest available. Some platforms that C++ wants to support don't have a X-bit type at all, and emulating one would be a significant burden. This is true for all values of X.

Answer (score 2):

The type `std::uint32_t` is supposed to be exactly 32 bits and an unsigned integer.

But this means it can be `unsigned int` or `unsigned long`.
Potentially both these values can be 32 bits long (depending on implementation).

> Or barring that any way to do defines telling me if std::uint32_t is not 32 bits so I can conditionally redefine the basic types?

The type `std::uint32_t` is defined to be 32 bits. This type is optionally defined and is not available if your platform does not have a 32 bit unsigned integer type.

Comment: this answer doesnt seem to match the question...

Answer (score 1):

Your desired code is:

```
#if (typeid(std::uint32_t) == typeid(unsigned long))
    typedef unsigned long Integer32;
#else 
    typedef std::uint32_t Integer32;
```

It's not legal, but what you're trying to say is, in other words "if `uint32_t` means `unsigned long`, then `Integer32` means `unsigned long`. Otherwise, it means whatever `uint32_t` means".

That's equivalent to:

```
typedef std::uint32_t Integer32;
```

because in both cases you're aliasing `Integer32` to mean the same type that `uint32_t` means. So just write that.

It is guaranteed that `uint32_t` is an unsigned 32-bit type in a conforming implementation. Since it's not `unsigned long` on your implementation, then it's almost certainly `unsigned int`. Those two types, `unsigned long` and `unsigned int`, are distinct types even if they're the same size. By contrast, `uint32_t` is a typedef, so it's the same type as whatever it's typedefed to mean.

To answer your new question:

```
typedef unsigned short Integer16;
```

`unsigned short` might not be exactly 16 bits (although there aren't many implementations on which it isn't). If you want an exact 16 bit unsigned type then that's what `uint16_t` is for. It's an optional type, so on implementations that don't have a suitable type your code will result in an informative error, which is almost as well as you can do.

```
typedef std::uint32_t Integer32;
```

OK, with the warning that `uint32_t` is an optional type. If you prefer the name `Integer32` then you're free to use it.

```
typedef unsigned int FastInteger16;
```

Use `std::uint_fast16_t` rather than `unsigned int` if you want a fast unsigned integer of at least 16 bits.

```
typedef unsigned long FastInteger32;
```

Use `std::uint_fast32_t` rather than `unsigned long` if you want a fast unsigned integer of at least 32 bits.

Comment: I guess typeid is a function and defines can't do functions, at least that code blows up for me with 'function call is not allowed in a constant expression'.

Comment: @Ryan: `typeid` is an operator, not a function. But you're correct that you can't use it in preprocessor conditionals. I guess the reason the error says "function" is that the preprocessor is reporting the error, and the preprocessor doesn't know that although `typeid(X)` looks like a function call, it isn't one.